Qiskit: Evolve TrotterQRTE from Operator
I am trying to implement the method in the following paper: Exponential Quantum Speedup in Simulating Coupled Classical Oscillators using Qiskit.
All is good until I call evolve on TrotterQRTE. It is expecting a (Sparse)PauliOp but I want top use an Operator as this can be created from a matrix much more generically.
Is there a way to convert an Operator to a (Sparse)PauliOp, or use TrotterQRTE in a different way?
For simplicity I am currently using the following Hamiltonian:
$$
\mathcal{H}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But it is not necessarily this simple.

You can use SparsePauliOp.from_operator() method to construct a SparsePauliOp from an Operator:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

H = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
]

op = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(H)

